# jQuery: Append HTML if tag contains specific class

Tags: jquery, html, css, append

I think this should be fairly simple to do, but Google isn't producing any results so hopefully someone here might be able to help.

Using jQuery I want to append some HTML inside an element if it contains a ul with a specific class.

So if a "main-menu li" element contains "ul.sub-menu" I want to append the "expand" div inside the "main-menu li" element which contains it.

Here's the HTML I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/4pwN9Rte

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.main-menu > li').find('ul.sub-menu').parent('li').append($('<div/>').addClass('expand'));
```

**Explanation:**

Take the `li` childs of the `.main-menu` list, find the `ul` sub-menu and append a new `div` with class expand to its parent li element.

OR the shorter version:

```
$('.main-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append($('<div/>').addClass('expand'));
```

Here is a jsfiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/03j5fkyh/1/

Comment: don't forget to close your question by setting the solution as the answer at the left side

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if($("main-menu li ul").hasClass("sub-menu")){
      $("main-menu li").append("#expand");
 }
```

hope it would work

Comment: this will add the div inside the ul list not after it, also what if its not the last ul list?

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood it

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, indeed! cheers! [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/3538bd8830b8397d0169bf6ac7c52135)

```
$('li:has(.sub-menu)').prepend('<div class="expand">asdfasdfasdf</div>');
```